# COM objects in list all point to the last object that was added

Tags: c#, .net, list, com

I have a class, let's call it MyClass, with several properties, one of which is a COM object (IFeature from ESRI ArcObjects).  The other properties are standard .NET objects.  So it looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   //COM object
   public IFeature Feature { get; set; }
   public MyOtherClass Other { get; set; }
}
```

This guy gets added to a list on another class through an Add method.  Then those MyClass objects get enumerated in a foreach loop in the class with the list.  Something like:

```
public DoStuffClass()
{
   private List<MyClass> myClasses;

   public void Add(MyClass myClass)
   {
      this.myClasses.Add(myClass);
   }

   public void DoStuff()
   {
      foreach (MyClass myClass in this.myClasses)
      {
         //Do stuff here.
      }
   }
}
```

I have noticed strange behavior.  The Other property gets enumerated correctly - when I debug I see that it goes through each of the objects that are in the list and grabs the current value.  But the Feature property always points at the value in the very last MyClass object in the collection.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Is there some weird COM thing going on that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Show the code that calls `DoStuffClass.Add`, and the code that creates your `MyClass` objects (if separate). I suspect you simply have an object in the wrong scope.

Comment: I did a test in the Add method where I checked the values in the Feature property of the objects being added, and they were correct, so I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: Depending on how you checked, that might not have helped. E.g. http://ideone.com/8I4oXR

Comment: Could well be a bug.  If you think this COM server misbehaves then you'll need to contact the author of the component for support.

Comment: This could be some kind of closure issue.  Really without seeing the code it is hard to tell.

Answer (score -1):

Tim S. was right about the type of issue.  I had to trace the creation of the Feature back to its source and discovered that the FeatureCursor class I was using to retrieve features from the database was set to recycle features.  Once I changed that parameter to false, it worked correctly.

```
IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(queryFilter, false);
```

The second parameter is for recycling.  That is what I set to false to achieve the desired behavior.